# Simulink: resistor with variable resistance during simulation

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape

I´m trying to find a way to change the resistance in a resistor during simulation in simulink. 
I have been using the fundamental blocks in the SimPowerSystem package from Simscape and I have a functional circuit for non-variable resistors.
What I want is a resistor block were instead of the parameter R (ohm) I could insert a vector with different resistance values. Is there such a block or is there a way to create a block of this kind?

I will be using this to model a thermal equivalent circuit for a loudspeaker and this variable shifting resistance is supposed to model the forced convection created by the membrane during operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simscape has a [variable resistor block](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ref/variableresistor.html). You should be able to use that instead. The instantaneous resistance value is provided as a physical signal input to the block.

[image]

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92766-how-can-i-create-a-variable-resistor-for-use-in-simpowersystems Here you can take more information about this block and several examples.

Comment: Thank you! That should work, it seems though that it isn't compatible with the SimPowerSystems.
 But I will just have to either find a coupler between the systems or redo the model using the blocks that is connectable with that block.

Comment: It depends which version of SimPowerSystems you use. The latest is compatible with Simscape, but not sure when the switch occured.